# Spring Rest path Conflict with @PathVariable and @MatrixVariable

Tags: java, spring, rest

I'm using Spring 4.1.9.RELEASE

Configured next Rest Controller.

And founded what /get/{id} somehow hide mapping for /get/matrix/{vars}

When i was trying call it by next url http://localhost:8080/testMatrixVariables/get/matrix/;v1=1;v2=2;v3=3
I've got from debug log

org.springframework.beans.TypeMismatchException: Failed to convert value of type [java.lang.String] to required type [long]; nested exception is java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "matrix"

Seems it's try parse {id} from my url but not /get/matrix/{vars}

I the same time next call works perfect
http://localhost:8080/testMatrixVariables/getMatrix/;v1=1;v2=2;v3=3
and 
http://localhost:8080/testMatrixVariables/get/1
as well works fine
and 
http://localhost:8080/testMatrixVariables/get/anotherPathVariable/2
also works

So problem only when we have conflict between @PathVariable and @MatrixVariable

http://localhost:8080/testMatrixVariables/get/matrix/;v1=1;v2=2;v3=3

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "/testMatrixVariables")
public class TestController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/get/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public
    @ResponseBody
    ResponseEntity<String> getByPathVariable(@PathVariable("id") long v1) {
        return ResponseEntity.ok("ok" + v1);
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/get/anotherPathVariable/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public
    @ResponseBody
    ResponseEntity<String> getAnotherPathVariableByPathVariable(@PathVariable("id") long v1) {
        return ResponseEntity.ok("ok" + v1);
    }


    @RequestMapping(value = "/getMatrix/{vars}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public @ResponseBody ResponseEntity<String> getMatrix(
            @MatrixVariable(pathVar = "vars", required = true) String v1,
            @MatrixVariable(pathVar = "vars", required = true) String v2,
            @MatrixVariable(pathVar = "vars", required = true) String v3) {
        return ResponseEntity.ok("ok" + v1 + v2 + v3);
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/get/matrix/{vars}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public @ResponseBody ResponseEntity<String> getGetMatrix(
            @MatrixVariable(pathVar = "vars", required = true) String v1,
            @MatrixVariable(pathVar = "vars", required = true) String v2,
            @MatrixVariable(pathVar = "vars", required = true) String v3) {
        return ResponseEntity.ok("ok" + v1 + v2 + v3);
    }

}
```

Comment: could you try sending "v1=1;v2=2;v3=3". I don't know if will work but you can give it a try.

Answer (score 1):

This is not working because Matrix variable is disabled by default.
It can be enabled in two ways:

1. Set the removeSemicolonContent property of RequestMappingHandlerMapping to false. By default it is set to true.
   Ex: handler.setRemoveSemicolonContent(false);
2. Or if you are using xml configuration then it can be done as

```
<mvc:annotation-driven enable-matrix-variables="true"/>
```

Comment: It's already done and matrix variable works 
"I the same time next call works perfect "

http://localhost:8080/testMatrixVariables/getMatrix/;v1=1;v2=2;v3=3 

Only particular scenarios doesn't work

Comment: After adding <mvc:annotation-driven enable-matrix-variables="true"/>, it should work. I have used the same program and url http://localhost:8080/testMatrixVariables/get/matrix/vars;v1=1;v2=2;v3=3. It worked for me

Answer (score 0):

Try putting

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/get/matrix/{vars}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public @ResponseBody ResponseEntity<String> getGetMatrix(
        @MatrixVariable(pathVar = "vars", required = true) String v1,
        @MatrixVariable(pathVar = "vars", required = true) String v2,
        @MatrixVariable(pathVar = "vars", required = true) String v3) {
    return ResponseEntity.ok("ok" + v1 + v2 + v3);
}
```

Above

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/get/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public @ResponseBody ResponseEntity<String> getByPathVariable(@PathVariable("id") long v1) {
    return ResponseEntity.ok("ok" + v1);
}
```

Ordering matters in as narrow mappings should come first followed by broader mappings.

Answer (score 0):

By default, Spring truncates URI content after semicolon

According to [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-ann-matrix-variables):

> Note that to enable the use of matrix variables, you must set the removeSemicolonContent property of RequestMappingHandlerMapping to false. By default it is set to true.

This one worked for me (with your example):

```
@Configuration
public class WebConfig extends DelegatingWebMvcConfiguration {

    @Override
    @Bean
    public RequestMappingHandlerMapping requestMappingHandlerMapping() {
        final RequestMappingHandlerMapping handlerMapping = super.requestMappingHandlerMapping();
        handlerMapping.setRemoveSemicolonContent(false);
        return handlerMapping;    
    }
}
```